# EWS c# обновление EmailAddresses

Tags: c#, сервер, email, exchange, ews

Есть объект `Contact` который отображает существующий на `Server Exchange` контакт. Пытаюсь обновлять значения коллекции `EmailAddresses` в некоторых случаях их нужно удалять. Код примерно такой:

```
String dbaseEmail1 = (string)xPerson.Element("eMail");
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbaseEmail1)) 
    contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = null;
else 
    contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = new EmailAddress(dbaseEmail1); 

String dbaseEmail2 = (string)xPerson.Element("Email2");
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbaseEmail2))
    contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress2] = null;
else
    contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress2] = new EmailAddress(dbaseEmail2); 

String dbaseEmail3 = (string)xPerson.Element("Email3");
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbaseEmail3))
    contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress3] = null;
else
    contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress3] = new EmailAddress(dbaseEmail3); 

contact.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

Так вот, создание/обновление `e-mail` адреса происходит без проблем, но вот удалить адрес до конца как-то не получается. А именно, после "удаления" через присвоение `null` и после повторного обращения к уже новому объекту `Contact`, ссылающегося на тот же контакт, действительно невозможно получить значение адреса. Т.е. если адрес был удален, то и `email1` будет теперь `null`:

```
EmailAddress email1;
contact.EmailAddresses.TryGetValue(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, out email1);
```

Но в **MS Outlook** адрес присутствует и никуда не делся, но возвратить его средствами **EWS** не получается. Нужно добиться его полного удаления.